# Правильное написание SQL запроса в opencart

Tags: php, sql, opencart, связи

Здравствуйте. 
Мог бы кто-нибудь мне помочь написать правильный запрос для выбора нужных товаров?

Введение:
- В магазине есть артикулы товара, я использую поле "model"
- Есть артикул замены, использую поле "sku"

Артикул замены - это артикул аналогичного товара. (поля заполняются вручную в админке)

Пример:
Товар №1
Артикул - xxxxxx
Артикул замены - yyyyyy

Товар №2
Артикул - yyyyyy
Артикул замены - xxxxxx

Артикулов замены на одном товаре может быть до 3-х штук.

Что я сделал:
в контроллере продукта

```
$this->data['productsArtZam'] = array();

$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductArtZam($this->request->get['product_id'],$this->data['sku'], $this->data['model']);

foreach ($results as $result) {     
    $skus = explode(',', $result['model']);

    foreach ($skus as $sku) {
        $this->data['productsArtZam'][] = array(
            'sku'        => trim($sku),
            'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
        );          
    }
}
```

В модели продукта ...

```
public function getProductArtZam($product_id, $sku, $model) {

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " 
. DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " 
. DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
        WHERE (sku LIKE '%" . $model . "%' AND quantity > 0 AND status = '1' ) LIMIT 1,6 ");

}
```

в tpl продукта вывожу артикул тех продуктов, которые соответствуют запросу.

У меня это работает так:
я заполняю поле артикул(model) и, через запятую, Артикул замены (sku). Разбиваю строку на массив, сравниваю и вывожу.
Чтобы эти арт. зам. выводились их нужно прописать в обоих товарах

Кажется, что все у меня получается, я получаю нужные товары, до 3-х шт. с активными, правильными ссылками.

НО

из-за LIKE %...% у меня все не получается. Есть два разных товара с разными артикулами: артикул ART-38 и ART-3. Артикул замены применяется и к ART-38 и ART-3, а должен только к первому.

Вместо LIKE делаю "=" все работает, как надо, но не выводится больше 1-го артикула замены, т.е. если в ...

Товар №2
Артикул - yyyyyy
Артикул замены - xxxxxx и zzzzzz

... то запрос, как бы не устраивает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Может вместо `LIKE` вам нужно `IN`:

`WHERE (sku IN (" . $sku . ")`